# Toggle Switch - Set Values

Tags: php, html, css

I want to implement a toggle Slider/Switch in my App.

The switch is used for the activation of an item.
I have a database with the cloumn "activation_status" and I want that if the switch is toggeled the entry is set to 1 (activated) and if the switch is not toggled the entry will be set to 0.

This is my HTML Code:

```html
<div class="toggle">
    <label>
      <input id="checkValue" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" />           
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

How could I set the values for my Switch?

The Button: [[image]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only need two values for your checkbox, you can handle it like so:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    // Set "activation_status" to 1.
} else { 
    // Set "activation_status" to 0.
}
```

If a checkbox is unchecked, the corresponding value in PHP will simply not be set. So if you try to retrieve the value of `$_POST['checkbox']` when the checkbox is unchecked, it will throw an error.

In case you need a slider with a range of values, you can also check out the HTML5-only [`<input type="range"/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range).

Answer (score 0):

add **jquery** code:

```
  if(document.getElementById('isAgeSelected').checked) {
        $("#txtAge").show();
    } else {
        $("#txtAge").hide();
    }
```